# How to send extra data (ViewBag) to the UI when a webform file is calling an MVC action via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a popup called **QuoteTemplateSelector.aspx** which has a button called **btnOK**.

```
 <dxe:ASPxButton ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Confirm and Export Quote">
     <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){
          e.processOnServer = false;

           <!-- more validation code here... -->         

            this.location = '/Projects/ExportQuote/' +projNumber                                
      }" />
  </dxe:ASPxButton>
```

the server side code is an MVC controller that returns a file.

```
public ActionResult ExportQuote(string projectNumber)
{
 //more code here ...


 //ViewBug.WarningMessage = "The following languages are not supported... 

 return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", quoteFileName);
}
```

If the operation goes well, an Excel file is downloaded to the user's browser (as a popup). Now I'd like to send extra information when things go wrong or just to display a warning to the user.

I know that if the UI were an MVC view, I could just snick the warning using the **ViewBag**. However, the client being an ASPx file, I don't know whether it's going to work.

Any suggestion? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as a two-step process like so:

```
<dxe:ASPxButton ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Confirm and Export Quote">
     <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){
          e.processOnServer = false;
          $.getJSON('/Projects/ValidateQuoteExport/' +projNumber, function (result) {
              if(result.validated) {
                  this.location = '/Projects/ExportQuote/' + projNumber
              } else {
                  // display result.errorMessage to user
              }
          });
      }" />
  </dxe:ASPxButton>
```

Then add an ActionResult for your Validation like so:

```
public JSONResult ValidateQuoteExport(string projectNumber)
{
    // Do the validation that you need
    return Json(new { validated = trueorfalse, errorMessage = errorMessage });
}
```

Making sure you put all of your validation code into a common function that you could call before serving the file, just in case someone URL bypassed the Validation.

Comment: what if things go well, but I just want to display a warning along before or after the file downloads?

Comment: Although I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, you *could* dump an iframe $("body").append("<iframe src=etc to the page, with the src being the File Result, that way you can bring up a message and initiate the download of the file all at the same time.